# Rails 4 fields_for not displaying field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models that I would like to create with one form. I tried following this [railscasts tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1), but I just can't get the nested fields to display on the form. How can I make these nested fields appear?

**Models**

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :poll_answers, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :poll_answers, allow_destroy: true
end

class PollAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :poll
end
```

**Controller**

```
class PollsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @poll = Poll.new
    2.times { @poll.poll_answers.build }
  end

  private

  def poll_params
    params.require(:poll).permit([
      :question,
      poll_answers_attributes: [:answer]            
    ])
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<%= form_for(@poll) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :question %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :question %>
  </div>

  <% f.fields_for :poll_answers do |pa| %>
    <p>Hello
      <%= pa.text_field :answer %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

  <%= debug @poll.poll_answers %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: For one, change `<% f.fields_for :poll_answers do |pa| %>` to `<% f.fields_for @poll.poll_answers do |pa| %>`

Comment: The docs show that its not necessary if its the same name. Works fine this way. Kyle nailed it. I cried.

Comment: Ah yes.  I didn't see where `:poll_answers` was getting defined but no matter glad it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed an `=`

```
 <%= f.fields_for :poll_answers do |pa| %>
    <p>Hello
      <%= pa.text_field :answer %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
```